# Get place names using CLGeocoder (not street names)

Tags: iphone, google-maps, ios5, reverse-geocoding, clgeocoder

I want to develop my own maps app. I have been successful in getting a street address at the point of touch on my iPhone using `CLGeocoder`. Now my question is the following:

1. I know that you can get information about a place by using a URL like `https://maps.google.com/?q=37.324599,-122.031844`
2. If you click on the above URL, it will take you near a church in Cupertino. Now `CLGeocoder` will only give me its street address i.e. `10110 N De Anza Blvd Cupertino, CA 95014` (I get this). But how to get the actual name i.e. `St Joseph of Cupertino Church and Parish`?
3. We can see it on Google Maps that means they must have it stored somewhere right?

Is there any way to access those place names (Not just by `CLGeoCoder`, any way is fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GeoCoding API in general is for converting between street addresses and coordinates. If you want place names you can probably use the Places API.

(I know this is more of a comment than an answer, but I think I don't have enough reputation points to comment on questions yet)

Comment: Thanks. Your keyword is at least now pointing me in right direction. I will look into several posts.

Comment: Here is the relavent API doc reference: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceSearchRequests

Answer (score 0):

YOu need t odo like this way after getting lat long use this code by CLLocation manager class

{

```
CLGeocoder *reverseGeo = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

[reverseGeo reverseGeocodeLocation: loc completionHandler: 
 ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

     NSLog(@"%@",[placemarks objectAtIndex:0]);
     for (CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks) {



         NSLog(@"~~~~~~~~%@",placemark.locality);

     }


 }];
```

}